# Is there a way to pass property substitution as an argument during runtime with Liquibase? Please share an example?

Tags: liquibase

I wan't my build script to be set with an environment variable that sets the schema name for the following changeSet:

```
<createTable tableName="actor" schemaName="mySchema">
        <column autoIncrement="true" name="id" type="INTEGER">
            <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="actor_pkey"/>
        </column>
        <column name="firstname" type="VARCHAR(255)"/>
        <column name="lastname" type="VARCHAR(255)"/>
        <column name="twitter" type="VARCHAR(15)"/>
    </createTable>
```

I launch Liquibase from the command line in my build script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pass arguments that will change from environment to environment, Liquibase uses property substitution.  This requires 2 changes to your existing process.

The first is to replace literal values with a variable:

I want my build script to be set with an environment variable that sets the schema name for the following changeSet (we will use the property name of SCHEMA below):

```
<createTable tableName="actor" schemaName="${SCHEMA}">
        <column autoIncrement="true" name="id" type="INTEGER">
            <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="actor_pkey"/>
        </column>
        <column name="firstname" type="VARCHAR(255)"/>
        <column name="lastname" type="VARCHAR(255)"/>
        <column name="twitter" type="VARCHAR(15)"/>
    </createTable>
```

Then we can pass a value for SCHEMA during command line creation, and to prove what value will be substituted, I used (note lookup is the name of the schema I want to substitute):

```
liquibase --changeLogFile=“sample.xml” updateSQL -DSCHEMA=lookup
```

And here is a snippet of the output which will show that the schema has been replaced with the value of lookup:

```
....
CREATE TABLE lookup.actor (id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL, firstname VARCHAR(255), lastname VARCHAR(255), twitter VARCHAR(15), CONSTRAINT actor_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id));
...
```

And if that looks okay, you can actually run the changeset by:

```
liquibase --changeLogFile=“sample.xml” update -DSCHEMA=lookup
```

Comment: This is great.  Thank you!

Comment: Change Log Properties:
 -D<property.name>=<property.value>         Pass a name/value pair for
                                            substitution in the change log(s)

Comment: ./liquibase-4.1.1/liquibase \
--logLevel=INFO \
update \
-DMyCustomThing=MyCustomValue

Comment: Thanks ronak... .for the COMPLETE example.  I was missing that the -D comes AFTER the "update" statement.  Lost an hour on that syntax sugar snapfu.